# Is there a word for the behaviour of interpreting your own opinion into something else to make it seem to you like it shares your opinion?

Tags: single-word-requests

I think my formulation in the title may be a bit confusing.
I mean a behaviour similar to "gaslighting" yourself into seeing/perceiving your own opinion from someone/something, even though that person/thing doesn't actually share your opinion.

I've witnessed this a few times on social media when people interpreted satirical videos of political topics to match their own opinions/believes, even though the videos themselves were neutral/not actually picking a side in the political topic.

Would be cool if there were a word for that.

Comment: As the tag text suggests, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: wIll remember to do that next time. Thanks. 

Answer (score 2):

This fits the meaning of the idiom ***put words in sb's mouth***:

> If you say that someone is *putting words into your mouth* or is putting words in your mouth, you mean that *they are suggesting that you mean one thing when you really mean something different*. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-put-words-into-someones-mouth#:%7E:text=If%20you%20say%20that%20someone,you%20really%20mean%20something%20different.))

A synonym would be *[twist smb's words](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/twist%20someone%27s%20words)*.

But since you are looking for one word, I would suggest ***misrepresent***:

> to describe falsely an idea, opinion, or situation, often in order to get an advantage ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/misrepresent))

Comment: Amazing, thank you!

Comment: @Joschka Remember that you can accept an answer :)